# Odoo 10 - Associating Account Number with Customer

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10

I am developing a custom module to handle customer accounts in Odoo 10. In my module, I have a char field where the user is supposed to place the account number. I also inherit **res.partner** and add a many2many field related to the account number model. Every customer can be associated with many account numbers. But every account number must only be associated with one customer. The problem and confusion I'm experiencing is how to get these fields to synchronize.

**models.py**

```
class partner_account_number(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    _description = 'Account Number'

    account_number = fields.Many2many('mymodule.account', string='Account number')

class account(models.Model):
    _name = 'mymodule.account'
    _description = 'Account'

    name = fields.Char(string='Account Number', required=True)

    customer_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Customer', required=True)
```

As you can see from my code, I add a field to **res.partner** which is related to **mymodule.account**. This means that if I create or edit a customer, I can enter an account number under the appropriate field and thus associate the customer with an account or accounts. However, to even input that account number, it first needs to be created under the **mymodule.account** model. When I create an account under that model, I input an account number under the **name** field, and add a customer under the **customer_id** field. But, to input a customer, there first must be one already created! This is where it begins to get confusing. How am I able to properly associate the customer with the account and also associate the account with the customer? Is there some code I can add which automatically adds the account number to the customer's information when I create an account?

Comment: You can use a computed many2many field.